# Length of tangents in circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

> The chord of contact of tangents from a point $P$ to a circle passes through $Q$, if $l_1$ and $l_2$ are length of tangents from $P$ and $Q$ to the circle, then $PQ$ is equal to?

I tried using power of point but didn't helped, please give some hints.

[image]

Comment: A quick play in GeoGebra suggests the answer is $\sqrt{{l_1}^2+{l_2}^2}$, but I'm struggling to find a proof.

Comment: @nickgard yes, I got my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be as follows.

Let the circle have centre $O$ and let the 'centre' of the chord of contact be $R$.

Find $OR$ and $PR$ in terms of the radius, $r$, of the circle and $l_1$.

Then $|PQ|^2=|QR|^2+|PR|^2=r^2+ {l_2}^2-|OR|^2+|PR|^2.$

Pythagoras also gives  $|PR|^2= {l_1}^2-r^2+|OR|^2$ and so $$|PQ|^2={l_1}^2+{l_2}^2.$$

Answer (score 4):

[image]

According to the Stewart’s theorem 
for $\triangle QPK_2$,
\begin{align} 
l_1^2\,n+x^2\,m&=(m+n)(l_1^2+mn)
,\\
m(x^2-l_1^2-mn-n^2)&=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

The power of point $Q$
provides

\begin{align} 
n\,(m+n)&=l_2^2
,\\
mn+n^2&=l_2^2
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\end{align}

Combination of \eqref{2} with \eqref{1} gives

\begin{align} 
x&=\sqrt{l_1^2+l_2^2}
.
\end{align}